# How to Create Dynamic MessageListener in spring?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to create a dynamic message listener and put it into spring container.
i have some Spring configured listeners in my spring xml files which perfectly work.
but my listeners from code doesn't :(

here is what i did.

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

    Object queue = null;
    try {
        queue = appContext.getBean(queueName);
    } catch (BeansException e) {
    }
    if(queue==null) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder queueBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(ActiveMQQueue.class);
        queueBuilder.addConstructorArgValue(queueName);
        factory.registerBeanDefinition(queueName,queueBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
    }

    // creating listener bean

    String listenerName = "dynamicListener";
    BeanDefinitionBuilder listenerBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(listener);
    factory.registerBeanDefinition(listenerName,listenerBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

    // creating adapter bean
    String beanName = "dynamicAdapterListener";
    BeanDefinitionBuilder listenerAdapterBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(MessageListenerAdapter.class);
    listenerAdapterBuilder.addPropertyReference("delegate", listenerName);
    listenerAdapterBuilder.addPropertyValue("defaultListenerMethod", null);
    factory.registerBeanDefinition(beanName,listenerAdapterBuilder.getBeanDefinition());

    //creating container bean 
    BeanDefinitionBuilder listenerContainerBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
            .rootBeanDefinition(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyValue("destinationName", queueName);
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyReference("connectionFactory", "connectionFactory");
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyReference("messageListener", beanName);
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyValue("concurrency", String.valueOf(concurrency));
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyValue("cacheLevelName", "CACHE_AUTO");
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyValue("autoStartup", true);
    listenerContainerBuilder.addPropertyValue("sessionAcknowledgeMode", 1);
    String containerName = "listenerContainer";
    factory.registerBeanDefinition(containerName, listenerContainerBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) appContext.getBean(containerName);
    // i even initialized bean to make sure it works but does'nt:( 
    bean.afterPropertiesSet(); // which initialized bean
```

All beans are created and injected into Spring ApplicationContext; however the listener don't Listen to the specified Queue.

Any idea how can i create Queue/Listener/Container/ all at runtime ??

Comment: You are only adding `BeanDefinitions` (recipes on how to construct a bean), not actual bean instances. To make the recipes work you would have to stop and refresh the applicationcontext, which probably isn't what you want. What is it that you want to achieve by registering beans at runtime?

Comment: I can get the bean instances later from application context! what u mean by they aren't actual bean instances? i have a requirement to create dynamic message listeners and queues so i'm trying to create queue and listener and put it into spring context.

Comment: There are no beans up until the moment you try to get them. Before that they are only recipes and not beans. I still don't get your higher level requirement but alas. In your code you are also overriding definitions (you are reusing the same names over and over). The  `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` so you should be calling `start` to have it listen to queues. I

Comment: Thanks buddy i run the start and it works just fine :) about the requirement: I have some bundles (jar files) which are loaded dynamically by my application. they all need too listen some queues. queues and listeners need to be created dynamically so i'm writing  utility with function like this registerListenerForQueue(Class<? extends javax.jms.MessageListener> listener,  String queueName, int concurrency)

Comment: please make an answer about start() method. to accept it. maybe your answer help somebody else too.